# error on version change

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below line in my XML.

```
<part>
<title>P<content-style format="smallcaps">ART</content-style> 1: CONSTITUTION OF COMPANY</title>
<part>
```

and with the below XSLT i'm trying to retrieve the number(here it is 1).

```
<xsl:template match="part">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
     <section class="tr_chapter">
            <div class="chapter">
                <xsl:variable name="num_L">
                    <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(./title,':'))"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="num_S">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$num_L=1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',substring-before(./title/text(),':'))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(./title/text(),':')"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </xsl:variable>
                <a name="CLI_CH_{$num_S}"/>

                <xsl:variable name="cnum">
                    <xsl:choose>

                        <xsl:when test="starts-with(@num,'0')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@num,'0')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <div class="chapter-title">
                    <span class="chapter-num">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat('Chapter ',$cnum,' '))"/>
                    </span>&#x00A0;
                    <xsl:variable name="TiC">
                        <xsl:call-template name="TitleCase">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(normalize-space(title),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="$TiC"/>-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </div>              
                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::title)]"/>

            </div>
        </section>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//chapter"/>
</xsl:template>
```

when i run this, it is throwing some error. which use to work in XSLT 1.0, please let me know why this error and how to rectify it.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/In%20Progress/Company_Law_Practice_&_Procedure_xml/XSLT/CLI_CHAP.xsl:65: Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   Details: -     XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('2' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one')
```

I also tried the below statement, but there is no change in the result.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="./title/substring-before(text(),':')"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(normalize-space(./title/child::text()[2]),':')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly *don't* need to use `text()` here, since what you seem to care about is the complete string value of the `title` element.

`text()` gives you a sequence consisting of all the text nodes that are direct children of the element in question, so `./title/text()` is a sequence of *two* text nodes, one with the value `P` and the other with the value `1: CONSTITUTION OF COMPANY` (preceded by a space).  In XSLT 1.0 when you provide a set of several nodes in a context that expects a single string what you get is the string value of the *first* node in the set in document order (so just "P" in this example).  But XSLT 2.0 is stricter - `substring-before` expects its first parameter to be a *single* value, and if you give it a sequence of two values it will complain.

If you just use `substring-before(./title,':')` without the `/text()` then it should do the right thing, as this will operate on the string value of the whole `title` element, which is the concatenation of all its *descendant* (not child) text nodes, i.e. `PART 1: CONSTITUTION OF COMPANY`.

Comment: here i just need to retrieve `1`, when i use the statement that you gave, it is also fetching in `PART`, do i need to use a mix of substring-before and substring-after?